# Sending All Voice Recordings to Analog Telephony Voice Logger

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I want to send all extensions and conference bridge participants of asterisk  voice to a analog telephone cable which is connected to a voicelogger ( recorder system) . How can it be done ?. I think this is possible by connecting Analog phone cable to  ATA device ( linsys pap2) and sending stream to that ATA extension . But the challange is voicelogger  is not an automatic answer machain .

Answer (score 1):

First i have say you that idea is really strange. Asterisk can record all calls and record storage will cost much less then any analog device storage.

If you still insist you need it send to analog, you need multiple line analog device(every call record will require different wire). 
Also you need FXS dahdi card and/or sip fxs adapter to connect your recorder.

You can orginize recording by using ChanSpy and/Or Confbridge as "ghost" call to all your calls with other dialling your fxs recording bank.

Complexity of such dialplan will be above average and require significant efforts and asterisk knowledge. You can read this links to get idea.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Other options you can have is record by asterisk and play recorded files one-by-one to your analog recorder or just use usual computer to playback files to recorder.